# PHP showing image is not working

Tags: php, html, image, user-profile

Hello i am having a site which shows users their own profile picture. But i am unable to do so, I have built a code but it is not working & giving an error as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/u522159750/public_html/users/myaccount.php on line 156` i.e. the line `$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, name, avatar FROM users WHERE id="'.$id.'" ") ;`Can anyone suggest me what could be the possible reasons. The code for showing image is as follow---

```
    <p>
 <?php
 //We check if the users ID is defined

$db_host = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$db_username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$db_password = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
$db_database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die("Cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_database) or die("Cannot select the database");
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, name, avatar FROM users WHERE id="'.$id.'" ") ;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)):
<a href="http://www.mysite.tk/users/myaccount.php"> <img src="<?php echo $result->avatar; ?>" alt="<?php echo $result->name; ?>" width="200" height="300" /></a>
?> </p>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The part where you intend to output the link with the image, is html and should either be outside of the php part, or printed, as below.

```
 <?php
 //We check if the users ID is defined

$db_host = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$db_username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$db_password = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
$db_database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die("Cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_database) or die("Cannot select the database");
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, name, avatar FROM users WHERE id="'.$id.'" ") ;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) {
    print '<a href="http://www.mysite.tk/users/myaccount.php"> <img src="'.$result->avatar.'" alt="'.$result->name.'" width="200" height="300" /></a>';
}
?>
</p>
```

Comment: oh you don't need to print so much of html, his approach is correct, it's just the path where he is missing

Comment: Are you quite sure? I does not look valid, at all, to me.

Comment: oh yes sorry, he needs to `echo` out...right..but instead of printing out html with php, I wanted to tell you that

Answer (score 0):

after viewing at the browser, check the url src of each image, is it at the right path? and make sure the image is existed at the src path.

Comment: In view page source it looks like this <img src="">

Answer (score 0):

i will not show you a code or an example  but  this sugestions might be useful :

what does the avatar column in db takes ?  does it take the image name or name.extension 
or   location/name.extension

if it takes only the name : then you must define the location in php example

```
echo '<a href="#" > <IMG src="location/'.$avatar.'.jpg" alt="..." 
hight="200"width="200"/></a>';
```

but note : in this case all the avatars must be the same extension ( *.jpg )

if it takes  the name.extension  then you have just to define the location only

if it takes  location/name.extension then you problem is not the $avatar

but still can be the avatar's name itself  be sure to do not leave avatars names contains
white spaces or non english alphabet characters. you have to renam them.